# Is it possible to deadlock with two locks and just one method that acquires both locks while all other methods acquire just one?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, cas

Do I run the risk of deadlocking with the code below? Is there a better/safer way of doing this? Initially I thought about combining somehow two locks into one, but maybe I am pushing too hard here and the code below is safe and correct.

```
public void method1() {

    lock1.lock();
    //...
    lock1.unlock();
}

public void method2() {
   lock2.lock();
   //...
   lock2.unlock();
}

public void method3() {
   lock1.lock();
   lock2.lock();
   // ...
   lock2.unlock();
   lock1.unlock();
}
```

Comment: This should never deadlock, no.  Deadlock will only happen with 2 threads each getting 2 or more locks out of order.

Comment: @Gary could you provide an example using the above where you could produce a deadlock?

Comment: Do you understand what a deadlock is? Where in your code do you suspect one could occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, `method3` can't have `lock2` locked without `lock1` locked, so a deadlock cannot happen in that method.  Note that this doesn't prevent some kind of additional code not shown to acquire `lock2` before `lock1`, such as

```
public void method4() {
   lock2.lock();
   lock1.lock();
   // ...
   lock1.unlock();
   lock2.unlock();
}
```

This, when run concurrently with `method3` can produce a deadlock.